# Unit testing a void method in an internal static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, methods, void

How do we go about testing a void method without instantiating the object in the test class? I understand in an internal static class we are unable to use "new" to create an object to test it. I've unit tested by creating objects for non static class but I  haven't dealt with an internal static class and am stuck. Any guidance would be great.

Here is the class/method in question:

```
internal static class Util
{
    public static void AssertBytesEqual(byte[] expected, byte[] actual)
    {
        if (expected.Length != actual.Length)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            throw new CryptographicException("The bytes were not of the expected length.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Length; i++)
        {
            if (expected[i] != actual[i])
            {
                Debugger.Break();
                throw new CryptographicException("The bytes were not identical.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `InternalsVisibileTo` attribute to allow another project to access internal classes.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameOfYourUnitTestProject")]
```

This would allow your test project to call `Util.AssertBytesEqual`. It is common to put attributes applied at the assembly level in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

As for testing the actual method itself it looks like the only 'output', so to speak, is an exception. You would simply test that the method does or does not throw an exception for various inputs.